# How add dynamic fields in angular form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have to create a dynamic form where label and input fields will both are text-field(user will fill at run time). And user can add as many as fields he requires. I have requirements where I have to generate. property file in backend. Where key-value pair is required and the user decides how much key-value pair he needs.

[image]

Comment: You need to use `FormArray` of `FormGroup`. You should share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Create `FormGroup` as

```
  keyValueFA = new FormArray([this.newKeyValueFG]);

  propertyFG = new FormGroup({
    keyValue: this.keyValueFA,
  });
```

getter to create new FormGroup

```
  get newKeyValueFG(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      key: new FormControl(null),
      value: new FormControl(null),
    });
  }
```

Other methods to set, remove, get FormGroup

```
  get keyValueArrayFGControls(): FormGroup[] {
    return this.keyValueFA.controls as FormGroup[];
  }

  addNewKeyValueFG(): void {
    this.keyValueFA.push(this.newKeyValueFG);
  }

  removeNewKeyValueFG(index: number): void {
    this.keyValueFA.removeAt(index);
  }
```

In template iterate `keyValueArrayFGControls`

```
<form [formGroup]="propertyFG">
  <div
    formArrayName="keyValue"
    *ngFor="let fg of keyValueArrayFGControls; let i = index"
  >
    <div [formGroup]="fg">
      {{ i + 1 }})
      <div><input type="text" formControlName="key" placeholder="Key" /></div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="value" placeholder="Value" />
      </div>
      <button (click)="removeNewKeyValueFG(i)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addNewKeyValueFG()">Add</button>
</form>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3yephd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Once data is added and we want to update data  how we would do that.

Comment: You mean Once data is added in Form; you want to save it in db by API call?